# Libgdx Position camera in TiledMap

Tags: libgdx

I have create a sample tile map like this, I am confused on how to show the camera on the center of the tilemap or in a specific position.

[image]

the output looks like this. how do I make the camera show the center of the tilemap also how do I make the image show smaller

[image]

Comment: Can you please post code where you initialize your camera?

Answer (score 2):

The camera's position is always considered to be the center of the camera.
An uninitialized camera will point to (0,0) and show as much space to the top, bottom, left and right as the viewport allows.
You can set the position in the create method:

```
OrthographicCamera camera = new OrthographicCamera(width, height);
camera.position.set(camera.viewportWidth / 2f, camera.viewportHeight / 2f, 0);
camera.update();
```

Do not forget to call the update method after any changes or they will not be visible.
In order to show the camera in a specific position after creation you need to move the camera by calling

```
camera.translate(x,y,z);
```

To zoom in and out simply set the zoom:

```
camera.zoom = someFloat;
```

If this does not make sense i recommend researching more about the orthographic camera 
(https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Orthographic-camera)
and viewports (https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Viewports).

If this does not help at all, because I misunderstood something, post more information plus some code and we will figure something out.